# how to troubleshoot database connection issues

Tags: database

Recently I have upgraded to Maverick on my Mac. Prior to the upgrade I was running my test sites using sitename.local After upgrading sitename.local was no longer working. I fixed this by running

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.pre-update /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
sudo apachectl restart
```

in the commandline (thanks to [mallinson.ca](http://mallinson.ca/post/web-development-with-mavericks/)). This resolved the issue with the sitename.local not working, but now my sites do not seem to recognise my database.

How do I troubleshoot this issue? I assume due to the upgrade a path has changed (somewhere), but I don't know how to find what path is currently being followed and what path I should supply to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now.

go in to `app/etc/local.xml` and change

```
<default_setup>
    <connection>
        <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
```

to

```
<default_setup>
    <connection>
        <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
```